# React/Jest: Testing React Context methods (Result: TypeError: setScore is not a function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using React Context API to create a game.

In one of my components (GameStatus) I pull in some methods from the provider:

```
const context = React.useContext(MyContext);
const { setGameStart, setGameEnd, setScore } = context;
```

And in the component I invoke these three methods onClick of the start game button, which in turn sets the state back in the provider.

GameStatus Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyContext } from './Provider';

const GameStatus = ({ gameStart, gameEnd, score, total, getPlayers }: { gameStart: boolean, gameEnd: boolean, getPlayers: () => void, score: number, total: number }) => {
    const context = React.useContext(MyContext);
    const { setGameStart, setGameEnd, setScore } = context;
    return (
        <>
            {!gameStart && (
                <button onClick={() => {
                    getPlayers();
                    setScore(0);
                    setGameStart(true);
                    setGameEnd(false);
                }}>
                    Start game
                </button>
            )}
            {gameEnd && (
                <p>Game end - You scored {score} out {total}</p>
            )}
        </>
    )
}

export default GameStatus;
```

Then in my test file below I want to test that when the start game button is clicked the game is started (check the DOM has removed the button and is now showing the game).

But I'm not sure how to pull in the methods in to the test file as I get:

**Result: TypeError: setScore is not a function**

I tried just copying:

```
const context = React.useContext(MyContext);
const { setGameStart, setGameEnd, setScore } = context;
```

But then I get an invalid hook call as I can't use React hooks inside the test.

Any ideas? Or a better approach to testing this? Thanks

GameStatus Test

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { MyContext } from '../components/Provider';
import GameStatus from '../components/GameStatus';

test('should start the game', () => {
    const getPlayers = jest.fn();

    const uut = shallow(
        <MyContext.Provider>
            <GameStatus
                getPlayers={getPlayers}
            />
        </MyContext.Provider>
    ).dive().find('button');

    uut.simulate('click');

    console.log(uut.debug());
});
```

Comment: Hi @Joe Consterdine, Could you please provide the definition of your `MyContext`? Does it have a default `setScore` function defined in it's initial state. It does not look like you are providing the function as a prop to `MyContext.Provider`, which would make it unavailable for use in `GameStatus`.

Comment: Hi @rexessilfie.

`setScore` in MyContext is:

```setScore: (score: number) => setScore(score)```

and this is linked to using React state:

```const [score, setScore] = useState<number>(0);```

so essentially `setScore` passed to `MyContext` is just a function that updates the `score` state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps but since your first approach was to use hooks inside your test you could try to use a library for rendering hooks. I'm not familiar with enzyme but I used [React Hooks Testing Library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/) in order to render my hooks inside my tests.
You can use it like that:

```
let testYourHook= renderHook(yourHook);
```

`testYourHook` value is not dynamic, so you have to get the value everytime with:

```
testYourHook.result.current
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to not have to use a different library but I will look into this if there's no other solution.

Comment: To be honest, the approach really depends on what your test is supposed to be doing. If you want to unit test your GameStatus component you don't really need to render the hook at all. You just have to mock it, and then check the mocking function (how many times was called, when it was called etc) or var. 
If you want an integration test to check those hooks as well you need a way to render them.